# how to pass query string in a multipage html document

Tags: jquery

I have html document with 2 pages and am using html5, jquery and jquery mobile. I need to pass a value from onepage to another page. I am using url like test.html#page-b. How to pass query string through this url

Comment: `test.html?query=string#hash`.  The query string comes before the hash.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below:

```
     $(window).load(function() {
      window.location.href =  window.location.href?qs=XXX
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the query string *before* the hash in the URL.

```
test.html?query=string#hash
```